# Getting 'EPERM operation not permitted rename' error while resolving packages in Unity. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: unity-game-engine

whenever i start unity and it resolves packages i get this error-

```
An error occurred while resolving packages:

  One or more packages could not be added to the local file system:

    com.unity.ide.visualstudio: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\.tmp-9680-Q8nQTp3jPEPn\extract' -> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.18'
```

I get this error in unity 2019.4.21f1, 2021.3.25f1, 2022.3.0f1
I have NPAV antivirus which scan files whenever they are executed

I tried installing the new version 2022.3.0f1 of unity, but still the issue persists

i tried disabling the antivirus and it did not work

update- now i enabled this setting in unity engine properties but i get this error-[administrator is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVkka.png)

[error when run as administrator is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SkqD.png)

Comment: I'd try deleting the folder at `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\.tmp-9680-Q8nQTp3jPEPn`, I guess that's something a failed download left behind.

Comment: i deleted the entire cache folder still did not work in fact i deleted it 2 times

Comment: disable scanning of your dev area

Comment: i already tried that still nothing

Comment: now when i disabled run as admin i get the eperm error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by manually downloading the visual studio package from github-https://github.com/needle-mirror/com.unity.ide.visualstudio

then i pasted it in-C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com
and extracted it and renamed it from com.unity.ide.visualstudio master to com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.18     and relaunched unity and error was fixed!

plus the path to my project contained a space (be unity pls) i changed it to beunitypls so now it works